# What is the most probable speed in the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution, and how is it related to the most probable kinetic energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistics

I mathematically arrived at a conclusion that the most probable kinetic energy equals $0.5kT$. However this is not equal to the kinetic energy corresponding to most probable speed. Mathematically, this makes sense, but intuitively it does not to me. Surely the most probable kinetic energy should use the most probable speed in its calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Kinetic energy is equal to $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. The $v^2$ means that we can't take the same distribution to calculate the most probable value for both. Using the value of $0.5kT$ we can find the most probable value of $v^2$, and the root mean square of that, but we have to find $v_{mp}$ differently:

$p(v)=4\pi \frac{N}{V}(\frac{m}{2pi kT})^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2e^{\frac{-mv^2}{2kT}}$

We differentiate this and set it equal to 0, finding three possible values for $v_{mp}$: $0$, $\infty$ or $\sqrt{\frac{2kT}{{m}}}$; the third value is the one we take, as it corresponds to a maxima whilst the other two are minima.